How to calculate/estimate the effective tyre circumference?
So, my vehicle - for an example - sports 255/50 R17 tyres, which have a circumference of 2,158mm (according to the online tire size calculator.)   However, as any air-filled tyre, once it has to carry the weight of a vehicle, it develops a slight latch, giving a smaller radius and consequently a smaller circumference.

Now, assuming the car is driving straight - how much does it move forward for every revolution of the wheels?  By the 2,158mm calculated from the unloaded tyre, or by the somewhat smaller value I'd calculate from the latched tyre?
More generally, for a given tyre size, what factor is commonly used to translate tyre rotation into vehicle speed?

I think I know how to calculate it, from surfacelength on road, and loaded radius ( or unloaded radius minus deflection).
The centre of wheel moves the surfacelength forward, while wheel makes an angle, wich can be calculated from unloaded radius an surfacelength.
(360 degr/ that angle) x surfacelength on ground, is rolling-circumference / distance.
Found aproacing formula on agricultural site, is next.
(Unloaded radius + loaded radius) x pi.
Same is (unloaded diameter minus deflection) x pi.
But mind, this is not an exact calculation.
I daubt if tyremakers know the 100% exact formula.
Now where goes the missing treath , because tyre roles over the ground without slipping?
My idea is, that tire-segment moves backward to the ground 2 times.
1 time yust before coming to the ground, and yust after going from the ground.
This has to be compensated by forward movement yust before and after moving backward, and then still that treath-segment has not moved forward to the ground.
